# InputType for aws lambda net6 from EventBridge

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, .net-6.0

Following the documentation for aws lambda net6:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/csharp-handler.html
- or small tutorial https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-net-6-runtime-for-aws-lambda/

The high-level lambda code below handles an EventBridge event (when a PutObject event is performed in a specific Bucket). I want to change Stream to an AWSEvent class, but which one? S3Event is not correct.

```
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport;
using Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson;
var handler = async (Stream request, ILambdaContext context) =>
{
    using var stream = new StreamReader(request);
    Console.WriteLine(stream.ReadToEnd());
}

await LambdaBootstrapBuilder.Create(handler, new DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer())
    .Build()
    .RunAsync();
```

The json received:

```
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "20a46552-4c8f-baa2-1a4c-a2290d207777",
    "detail-type": "AWS API Call via CloudTrail",
    "source": "aws.s3",
    "account": "99999999999",
    "time": "2023-01-17T15:10:02Z",
    "region": "REGION",
    "resources": [],
    "detail": {
        "eventVersion": "1.08",
    ...
    "awsRegion": "REGION",
        "sourceIPAddress": "99.99.99.99",
        "userAgent": "[aws-cli/2.0.5 Python/3.7.3 Linux/4.18.0-80.4.2.el8_0.x86_64 botocore/2.0.0dev9]",
        "requestParameters": {
            "bucketName": "bucketName",
            "Host": "Host",
            "key": "key"
        },
    ...
}
```

Comment: Try using `Amazon.Lambda.CloudWatchEvents` & `Amazon.CloudTrail.Model` Nuget packages and `async (CloudWatchEvent<Event> request, ILambdaContext context)` - I haven't checked end to end but that should work? Can you try it and let me know?

Comment: Amazon.Lambda.CloudWatchEvents seems to be good. Unfortunately not Event, nor S3Event. I can't find the second type

Comment: S3Event seemed to be appropriate

Comment: S3Event is for an S3 trigger - you're using EventBridge. The types won't match the data you have.

Comment: `Event` is `Amazon.CloudTrail.Model.Event`